# Laravel Http Client cannot attach files contents required

Tags: laravel, http, post, httpclient, multipartform-data

I have been looking for the answer but failed to do so.

The problem is simple, I am trying to make an HTTP request using Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http class as documented here https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client#multi-part-requests.

My code:-

```
$picture = fopen(public_path('/temp_pass/image.jpeg'),'r');

$response = Http::attach('attachment', $picture)
             ->withHeaders(['Accept'=>'application/json'])
             ->post('mydomain.com/item/store',['item_id' => 'my_item_id']);
```

The picture URL is ok. The domain to send to also ok. Unfortunately, I got this error

```
A 'contents' key is required
```

I hope great developers here can help me solve this.

Answer (score 1):

The line `Http::attach('attachment', $picture)` refers to the following file and method.

**Illuminate\Http\Client\PendingRequest.php**

```php
public function attach($name, $contents = '', $filename = null, array $headers = [])
```

`A 'contents' key is required` occurs when `$contents` is falsy (empty, null, false, 0, etc.) based on my testing.

In your case, this refers to `$picture`. You should check that `$picture` actually contains a file stream as expected. Dump it before the HTTP request to test.

```php
dd($picture);

// stream resource @7 ▼
//   timed_out: false
//   blocked: true
//   eof: false
//   wrapper_type: "plainfile"
//   stream_type: "STDIO"
//   mode: "r"
//   unread_bytes: 0
//   seekable: true
//   uri: "/.../image.jpeg"
//   options: []
// }
```

Comment: i got this when dd stream resource @15 ▼
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  wrapper_type: "plainfile"
  stream_type: "STDIO"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: true
  uri: "/private/var/tmp/phppWwrLT"
  options: []
}

Comment: Is there any additional code between the `fopen()` and the HTTP request that you left out?

Comment: no additional code. i even try with file_get_contents(), and sure there is a file because i did try open it with browser.

Comment: Are you certain you have referenced the proper facade `use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;` and not a similarly named class from another package?

Comment: yes im sure. I did use use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http. Its working when i dont use attach method.

Comment: The `Http` facade uses Guzzle under the hood. Are all of your dependencies up to date?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228662/discussion-between-muhammad-habib-and-matticustard).