# Laravel 8 http::attach -> A 'contents' key is required

Tags: php, fopen, laravel-8, file-get-contents

```
$response = Http::attach('InputFile0', file_get_contents('test.docx'), 'test.docx')->withHeaders([
    'Authorization' => 'Bearer XYZ',
    'X-API-Key' => 'ABC123',
    'Content-Type' => 'multipart/form-data',
])->post('https://cpf-ue1.adobe.io/ops/:create', $data);
```

I get the response:

```
InvalidArgumentException
A 'contents' key is required
```

The file exists and is readable. Tested with

```
dd(file_get_contents('test.docx'));
```

I also tried

```
$file = fopen('test.docx', 'r');
```

but get the same error although when dumped i get to see a stream:

```
stream resource @433 ▼
  timed_out: false
  blocked: true
  eof: false
  wrapper_type: "plainfile"
  stream_type: "STDIO"
  mode: "r"
  unread_bytes: 0
  seekable: true
  uri: "test.docx"
  options: []
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel Http Client cannot attach files contents required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66181620/laravel-http-client-cannot-attach-files-contents-required)

Comment: Try a `var_dump(file_get_contents('test.docx'))` and see if the function returns a falsy value.

Comment: tried that, it's not a falsy value.

Comment: I am getting the same error on laravel 9 too, is there any solution to this?

Comment: Hey if someone still facing this, please check out my answer at https://stackoverflow.com/a/76920596/5273796