# Laravel post file with HTTP::attach error : A 'contents' key is required

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I try to send a file via the Http facade as described in the documentation I dont undestand what is failing, I dd the content $stage->pdfFile, I get it via file_get_contents() and it's not empty it's the datas of the file.

I always got the error : A 'contents' key is required.

```
public function sendPdfFile($id)
    {

        try {

            $stage = Stage::findOrFail($id);
            $stage->setPdfFileAttribute();

            //test
            //dd($stage->pdfFile);//ok

            $response = Http::attach('pdfFile',$stage->pdfFile,$stage->n_stage.'.pdf')
                ->post($this->endpointFileUploadUrl);


        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            $this->error("error sending file ".$stage->n_stage.".pdf to ".$this->endpointFileUploadUrl.' : '.$exception->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Here is the documentation about that https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/http-client

```
$response = Http::attach(
    'attachment', file_get_contents('photo.jpg'), 'photo.jpg'
)->post('http://example.com/attachments');
```

I changed it like that, same error :

```
public function sendPdfFile($id)
    {

        try {

            $stage = Stage::findOrFail($id);
            $stage->setPdfFileAttribute();

            //test
            //dd($stage->pdfFile);//ok

            $response = Http::attach('pdfFile',$stage->pdfFile,$stage->n_stage.'.pdf')
                ->post($this->endpointFileUploadUrl, [
'name' => 'pdfFile',
'contents' => $stage->pdfFile,
]);


        }catch(\Exception $exception){
            $this->error("error sending file ".$stage->n_stage.".pdf to ".$this->endpointFileUploadUrl.' : '.$exception->getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5):

For multipart requests only, you should pass each param & its content in an array as the 2nd parameter (array of array) of `post` method.

```
$response = Http::attach('pdfFile',$stage->pdfFile,$stage->n_stage.'.pdf')
->post($this->endpointFileUploadUrl, [
                [
                    'name' => 'param 1',
                    'contents' => 'param 1 contents'
                ],
                ....
    ]);
```

Comment: ok, it's not mentionned in the doc like that, I understand, I try.

Comment: It's weird to send the content that is already given in $stage->pdfFile in 'contents' ?

Comment: So 'param1 contents' is not equal to $stage->pdfFile here ?

Comment: I passed it as you can see in my edit, but the same error occurs

Comment: @SiddharthSathe I think you need to explain where the `'contents' => 'param 1 contents'` come from. that's very ambiguous

Answer (score 0):

If anyone still facing this issue, please find my code which works fine for me.

Request from Laravel Application 1

```
request = Http::withHeaders(['Accept' => 'Application/Json']);

        foreach ($this->files as $key => $file) {

            $request->attach("file{$key}", fopen($file['file']->getRealPath(), 'r'), $file['filename']);
        }

        $response = $request->post(
            "{$this->url}",
            [
                'firstname' => $this->firstname,
                'lastname' => $this->lastname,
                'phone' => $this->phone,
                'reference' => $this->reference,
                'file_count' => count($this->files)
            ]
        );
```

Code from Laravel Application 2 that handles incoming request

```
 $file_count = $request->file_count;

    for($i=0; $i<$file_count; $i++){

        Document::create([
            'name' => $request->file("file{$i}")->getClientOriginalName(),
            'path' => $request->file("file{$i}")->store('documents', 'public'),
        ]);
    }
```

Hope it helps someone..